# How to search for items in a list?

Tags: python

The code I am trying to produce is a program that lets the user enter a search term, and then it prints out matching searches. The context is lists within lists. The sublists are sentences and authors.

```
myList = [["Hello my name is Liam", "John Doe"], ["Hello my name is Jeff", "Jane Doe"]]

search = input("search: ")
for i in myList:
    for j in i:
        if search in j.lower():
            print('"{}"'.format(i[0]))
            print("--{}".format(i[1]))
```

The search works fine, but what I want to do, is when the search is run, it only searches for matches in the sentence, not the author. So if I searched `"John"` nothing would come up because thats in the author index not the sentence index.

I tried using

```
for j in i[0]:
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: `John` is being matched too; Its unclear to me what are you trying to achieve...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping through every sublist just check the list in index `0`:

```
search = input("search: ")
for i in myList:
    if search in i[0].lower():
        print('"{}"'.format(i[0]))
        print("--{}".format(i[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it out! enumerate() works wonders in most list/array situations.

```
myList = [["Hello my name is Liam", "John Doe"], ["Hello my name is Jeff", "Jane Doe"]]    
search = input("search: ")
for i in myList:
    for index, j in enumerate(i):
        if index > 0:
            continue
        if search.lower() in j.lower():
            print('"{}"'.format(i[0]))
            print("--{}".format(i[1]))
```

Don't forget to lowercase your search string, so it's case-insensitive. Consider tuplets for the inner arrays in this situation. I hardly ever find a reason to use them + unavailable in most languages I use, but if you need the structure you've presented, it's fitting.